# How to implement EVERY and NO operations for a joined 'list' table

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have two tables Person and _Person_Name which contains a column Name and a column Owner with Person.Id as foreign key. I'm looking for two search operations I'd call *EVERY* and *NO*.

**1.) *Every***

The following returns only the Person IDs for which *all* corresponding names match for query `LIKE '%n%'`:

```
SELECT Person.Id as Result FROM Person
INNER JOIN _Person_Name AS __T1 ON Person.Id = __T1.Owner 
WHERE __T1.Name LIKE '%n%'
GROUP BY Result
HAVING Count(Result)=(Select Count(*) FROM _Person_Name 
  WHERE Person.Id=_Person_Name.Owner)
```

But the problem is that I also have to deal with other queries for which just a single match suffices, and the HAVING clause applies to all terms in the WHERE clause.

Is there a way to get the same effect as in the HAVING clause in the above query, but somehow express this within the WHERE clause such that other, ordinary conditions can be added to it?

Example:

```
SELECT Person.Id as Result FROM Person 
INNER JOIN _Person_Name AS __T1 ON Person.Id = __T1.Owner
WHERE (EVERY __T1.Name LIKE '%n%') 
OR (__T1.Name LIKE 'John')
```

The second disjunct should just behave in the ordinary way without any restrictions. Now I'm looking for a way to express *EVERY* like in the above *HAVING* clause. The query should return `__T1.Owner` (=Person.Id) whenever it is the case that one field with matching owner has a name field `__T1.Name LIKE 'John'` or it is the case that *all* `__T1.Name` fields with matching owner contain an 'n'.

If it is not possible to express this in the WHERE clause, how can it be expressed?

**2.) *No***

The *NO* search operation is just like *EVERY* but the base condition is negated, i.e., I'm looking for the Persons for which none of their associated Name parts matches the query. I suppose I can get that easily if I have a solution for *EVERY*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me start with an idea for NO: you can check if no row exists if you look up by condition LIKE '%n%'. You can do it in the WHERE clause with EXISTS subquery:

```
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM _Person_Name AS __T2 WHERE Person.Id = __T2.Owner
        and __T2.Name LIKE '%n%'
        )
OR (__T1.Name LIKE 'John')
```

NOT EXISTS checks if there is NO match.

Based on this the implementation for EVERY is to see if the negation of your condition for no row is true, so you are looking for NOT LIKE '%n%':

```
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM _Person_Name AS __T2 WHERE Person.Id = __T2.Owner
        and __T2.Name NOT LIKE '%n%'
        )
OR (__T1.Name LIKE 'John')
```

This time NOT EXISTS will make sure no rows found that does NOT match your criteria - therefore EVERY row matched it.

Comment: Perfect! This works, with a small change. The inner SELECT would need a JOIN for the ON condition to work, instead I used: SELECT DISTINCT Person.Id as Result FROM Person 
INNER JOIN _Person_Name AS __T1 ON Person.Id = __T1.Owner
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM _Person_Name AS __T2
        WHERE __T2.Name LIKE '%n%' AND Person.Id=__T2.Owner
        )

Comment: Oh, I did it incorrectly, but you don't need a join there. Try my update.