# SQL query exists all

Tags: sql-server, exists

I need a query to list students that takes all available courses using two below tables.

```
declare @Course table (CourseID nvarchar(4))
declare @CourseStudent table 
                       (
                           CourseID nvarchar(4),
                           Student nvarchar(50)
                       )

insert into @Course values ('SOS1')
insert into @Course values ('MAT3')
insert into @Course values ('FEN2')

insert into @CourseStudent values ('MAT3', 'Mehmet')
insert into @CourseStudent values ('SOS1', 'Ahmet')
insert into @CourseStudent values ('MAT3', 'Ahmet')
insert into @CourseStudent values ('FEN2', 'Ahmet')
insert into @CourseStudent values ('SOS1', 'Ali')
insert into @CourseStudent values ('FEN2', 'Ayse')

select * from @Course

select * from @CourseStudent
```

Comment: What have you got so far? Are there students which take all those courses plus others?

Comment: With a proper primary key, all you need to do is count rows in CourseStudent. Do you have one or is it possible that a student might "take" the same course multiple times?

Comment: No, it's not possible to take same course multiple times.

Comment: I want to list the students who took all the courses in the course table.

Comment: For a solution that uses `EXISTS` see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53342896/how-to-implement-every-and-no-operations-for-a-joined-list-table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could nest some `not exists` queries. The solution below translates as follows:

1. Select all unique students...
2. Where there is no course...
3. That does not exist for that student.

**Solution**

```
select distinct cs.Student
from @CourseStudent cs
where not exists ( select 'x'
                   from @Course c
                   where not exists ( select 'x'
                                      from @CourseStudent cs2
                                      where cs2.CourseID = c.CourseID
                                        and cs2.Student = cs.Student ) )
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1437c0cdcbc55e3c7da1907be87f8052) to see things in action.

Answer (score 1):

This is a relational division question. There are a number of ways to solve it. The simplest in this case uses `COUNT`:

```sql
SELECT cs.Student
FROM @CourseStudent cs
GROUP BY cs.Student
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @Course);
```

This does not deal with the case of students taking courses which are not in `@Course`